# Equivalent of MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdownAll() in HttpClient 4.x

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

With `HttpClient` 3.x there was a static `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdownAll()` which we invoked from a `ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed()` to clean up all potentially hanging threads (prevent classloader leaks).

With `HttpClient` 4.x this is gone but there's `PoolingClientConnectionManager`. However, it's got no static methods to shutdown connections.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inclusion of this method in HC 3.1 was a mistake. Generally I can see no reason for having more than pool of connections per distinct HTTP service. It should not be that difficult to keep track of one or two connection managers and shut them down when necessary. Having said that, if for whatever reason you really need to shut down all active connection managers indiscriminately you can use the same technique as used by HC as of version 4.3-beta2 when running inside a OSGi container: basically keeping track of HttpClient instances created by a custom HttpClientBuilder and shutting them down when the container is shut down or the bundle is reloaded

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.3-beta2/httpclient-osgi/src/main/java/org/apache/http/osgi/impl/OSGiHttpClientBuilder.java

Comment: The code I'm porting to HC 4 is a few years old and I wasn't assigned to the project in more than 2 years. I believe with included that in our shutdown listener because Tomcat complained about classloader leaks if we didn't. The thing is, I can very well keep track of connections _my_ code opens but not those from 3rd party libs that use HC.

Comment: @Marcel: It is hardly HC's fault if a third party library does not provide a means of cleaning resources it allocates. You primary concern should be aboug ensuring the correct behavior of _your_ code. However, my main point is that one should rarely need more than one connection pool.

Comment: true, but I hope my comment doesn't imply it's HC's fault. Nonetheless, it was nice to have a means to make sure bad 3rd party libs don't affect the stability of my code.